# Unknown file type error with .pyx file

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a Python package (pyregion) that contains a *.pyx file and error comes during the build process. Checking out the below output:

```
$ python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7
....
running build_ext
building 'pyregion._region_filter' extension
C compiler: gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -arch x86_64

error: unknown file type '.pyx' (from 'src/_region_filter.pyx')
```

Any ideas on what the issue could be? Just to note, I'm using the Enthought build of Python (7.1) on OSX with the latest Xcode (4.1).

Cheers

Comment: this was the first hit on google for "unknown file type '.pyx'"... and I was also trying to install pyregion.  Well done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `.pyx` should should be compiled to C with Pyrex and then compiled to object code. Check if a `src/_region_filter.c` file is present in the distribution and hack the `setup.py` script to build that instead. (Also, consider [filing a bug report](https://github.com/leejjoon/pyregion/issues), since this shouldn't be happening.)

Comment: Probably Cython instead of Pyrex these days, but anyway +1

Comment: @delnan: no, Pyrex, see its [`setup.py`](https://github.com/leejjoon/pyregion/blob/master/setup.py).

Comment: Ah okay, didn't figure a project that small was old enough to have seen the days before Cython replaces Pyrex.

Comment: @larsmans You're suggestion was bang on. Edited the setup.py to remove any mention of the .pyx file and redirected it to the .c file. Compiled and running. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

python3.6 -m pip install Cython

Installing Cython solves the problem for me!

Answer (score 3):

Install pyrex first and it will work.

Do the following:
sudo pip install pyrex

Comment: This doesn't seem to be correct. The only package available is `Pyrex` (capitalized), whose package definition seems to be broken.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution to this problem for me, when attempting to install `pyFFTW`, was to first install `Cython` via `pip`. Also see https://github.com/pyFFTW/pyFFTW/issues/252 .

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error by using cython, but I solves it by change

```
cmdclass = {'build_ext ': build_ext },
```

to

```
cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext },
```

as you may not notice, redundant blank character behind `'build_ext '`.

Answer (score 0):

My own solution to the same error message you had: Cythonize your `*.pyx` files in the `setup.py` script

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
...
cythonised_files = cythonize("src/*.pyx")
```

(I tried installing Pyrex, but ended up with errors about unrecognised characters instead)

Further details here: http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html