# Unknown file type error with .pxd file

Tags: python, cython

I try to install [triangle](http://dzhelil.info/triangle/installing.html) for python on Kubuntu 14.04. Either if I try to install it via easy_install or from source, I receive the following error:

```
sudo easy_install triangle
Processing triangle
Writing /home/magnus/triangle/setup.cfg
Running setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /home/magnus/triangle/egg-dist-tmp-sJ6dHl
Searching for setuptools>=18.0
Best match: setuptools 19.2
Processing setuptools-19.2-py2.7.egg

Using /home/magnus/triangle/setuptools-19.2-py2.7.egg
/home/magnus/triangle/core.pyx:5:35: Expected an identifier or literal
error: Setup script exited with error: unknown file type '.pxd' (from 'triangle/c_triangle.pxd')
```

It seems to be a similar problem as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846084/unknown-file-type-error-with-pyx-file), but I can't figure out how to fix it. My Cython version is:

```
cython --version
Cython version 0.20.1post0
```

Does someone know how to fix this? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this error as well and solved it in the following steps:

1. clone the git repository of the triangle package:

   git clone https://github.com/drufat/triangle.git
2. Install the latest Cython (version==0.23)
3. In setup.py, search the keyword Cython and change its version requirement to >=0.23.
4. Run python setup.py install

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In fact I also had to upgrade my setuptools. Also, I removed pyrex, although I am not sure if this was really needed.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue while installing the triangle package in a virtual environment on xubuntu 14.04. I resolved it in my case by:

1. Upgrading setuptools (to version 19.4) by

   ```
   pip install --upgrade setuptools
   ```
2. Installing triangle by

   ```
   pip install triangle
   ```

My cython (version 0.23.4) was installed using

```
pip install --upgrade cython
```

Comment: Thank you! Just in-case people are wondering, this is still relevant in 2016, even for Mac users, helped solve my issue on OSX Yosemite